# Webeditor for developing a modern website

Tags: html, css, web

I created a webpage several years ago. Back then I was using Adobe GoLive! to achieve that. But now, there is no adobe GoLive any more and I don't have a useful application for creating a web project. So what I want to achieve is: a good looking online presence for my project. I want to use the new stuff as well, like HTML5 and CSS3. I don't think that I will need beans or J2EE, because it is more about the design and not the functionality. Later on I will include the web project into my Apache server. So the question is: which tool can help me to develop a modern website, what would you advice?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Actually I use NetBeans 8 for the following reasons:

1. it's very strong and containt so many features

   i   supports ftp

   ii  supports CSS3 , HTML5

   iii powerful , autoComplete
2. it's open-Source application so it's free
3. it keeps the history of your files and saves all the updates so you can restore any file

situation you made before

4. it's easy to use.

It's a good programming tool

SECOND: I suggest using xampp instead of abache server
it actually includes abache and some other features like mysql
so it's easy to deal with it instead of dealing with many programs :)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend 'IUEditor'

1. Free license. Ownership is 2,000$, monthly license is more than 50$. But if you request startup license they offer free license.
2. CSS3 and HTML5 : you can use any kind of website.
3. Back-end support : That's only one web editor which supports backend, such as django and angularJS
4. Supports GIT.

I tried more than 10 web editors, but IUEditor works best.